# Как я могу избежать memory error при генерации большого количества вариантов с помощью itertools.permutations

Tags: python, outofmemoryerror

У меня есть 2 функции, которые используют itertools.permutations. Как я могу решить memory error при создании массива с длиной хотя бы в 6 символов (если меньше, то все работает без проблем)

```
def generate_permutations(length):
       numbers = list(range(10))
       permutations = list(set(i for i in itertools.permutations(numbers, length)))
       return permutations

def get_all_variants(string: str) -> list[str]:
       def is_not_start_with_digit(item):
           return not item[0].isdigit()

       return sorted(filter(is_not_start_with_digit, list(set([''.join(p) for p in permutations(string)]))))
```

Comment: Решил проблему с помощью генераторов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажется, Вы зря формируете на промежуточных этапах множества и списки. Вот код, который на достаточно хилой машине "задумывается" секунд на 30 только на последнем шаге (11 символов, 21772800 вариантов). До memory error дожидаться было лень :) Надеюсь, я правильно понял задачу.

```
import itertools

def get_all_variants(string: str):
    return (''.join(p) for p in itertools.permutations(string)
                  if not p[0].isdigit())


for i in range(2, 12):
    q = sorted(get_all_variants('a1b2c3d4e5f6g7'[:i]))
    n = len(q)
    print(i, ":", n)
    if n < 100:
        print(q)
```

UPD. `set` в задаче, вероятно, нужен, но добавление в функции `return set(` практически не замедлило